# How to log filtered data in Kafka Stream?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I hava a kafka Stream and I perform a filter operation.
I would like to log those records **that get filtered out**.

```
streamsBuilder.stream(topicName)
.filterNot( (k,v) -> v.getExampleProperty() == null)
...
```

I would like to log those record with null ExampleProperty. 
I would like to use something like the peek() function but with some predicate. How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

The way you use it, you can write it directly behind the filter.
"Filter creates a new KStream that consists of all records of this stream which satisfy the given predicate."
The filter contains the same predicate as the peek:

```
streamsBuilder.stream(topicName)
.filter( (k,v) -> v.getExampleProperty() == null)
.peek( (k,v) -> {System.out.printf("key:" + k + "value" + v)})
```

when you want peek the **filtered out** records you could use the complementary filter in parallel:

```
.stream(topicName)
.filterNot( (k,v) -> v.getExampleProperty() == null)
```

If you do not want to filter twice the same stream you could use something like split(branch) instead of the filter(more on this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40921376/5528518)

Answer (score -1):

EDIT:

This is how I thought the problem could be solved:

```
.peek( (k,v) -> { 
    if (v.getExampleProperty() == null){ 
       System.out.printf("key: " + k.toString()); 
       System.out.printf("value: " + v.toString());
    }
})
```

However as pointed out by @OneCricketeer in the comments this approach could process unnecessary data.
It is better to use Filter and FilterNot followed by a peek for such a use case.

```
.stream(topicName)
.filter( (k,v) -> v.getExampleProperty() == null)
# ... your other code

# the filtered out print
.stream(topicName)
.filterNot( (k,v) -> v.getExampleProperty() == null)
.peek( (k,v) -> { 
   System.out.printf("key: " + k.toString()); 
   System.out.printf("value: " + v.toString());
}
```

Comment: This works, but is not recommended pattern. Use `filter().peek()`

Comment: Could you give some hint on why this is not recommended pattern?

Comment: Moreover I updated the question since I wanted to log the filtered out records, there was a misunderstanding. @OneCricketeer

Comment: I understood the question, and I said this will work, but it is better to extract your if statement expression to be returned by `filter()` / `filterNot()` functions as the other answer shows. Both work the same, but one is utilizing Kafka Streams functions more properly. Otherwise, your peek function is processing unnecessary data.